# Reliability calculation using R

Tags: r, anova, reliability

I have this handout about reliability calculation, but I just can't figure out how I could do this using R.

Here is the simulated data. It is a questionaire that has ten quaestions and was answered by 15 people.

```
                           The Data
Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4 Q5 Q6 Q7 Q8 Q9 Q10
0  0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 
1  0  0  0  0  1  0  1  1  1 
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
0  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  1  0 
1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  0 
1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 
1  1  1  1  0  1  1  1  0  1 
0  1  1  1  1  1  0  1  1  1 
1  1  0  1  0  0  1  1  0  0 
1  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  1  1 
0  1  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  1 
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
0  1  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0 
0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  1  0 
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1 


                          Analysis of Variance Table
   SOURCE                DF   SUM OF SQUARES   MEAN SQUARE   F VALUE
   MODEL                 23    14.98000000      0.65130435      3.71
   ERROR                126    22.09333333      0.17534392    PR > F
   CORRECTED TOTAL      149    37.07333333                    0.0001

   R-SQUARE          C.V.          ROOT MSE          S MEAN
   0.404064        93.7480       0.41874087      0.44666667

   SOURCE         DF        ANOVA SS       MEAN SQUARE    F VALUE    PR > F
   ISUB           14      14.17333333       1.0123809       5.77     0.0001
   ITEM            9       0.80666667       0.0896296       0.51     0.8643
```

I think the author uses SAS to produce the ANOVA table. My question is that how can I get this output in R? I kinda get why there are 23 DF for the model and 126 for the error. But I don't konw how I can get this using R. Thanks!!

Just in case more explanation is needed. The handout followed with this:

The model for our current example looks like the following: QT = ISUB + Item (ISUB and Item are factors). A subject's total score, QT, is predicted by influences for the subject (true differences between subjects) as well as influences for each item. Relative to the model QT is the score on the test of interest. ISUB represents the subject. There are l5 different examinees and each is expected to have some true score on the ability being measured by this test. A separate parameter is estimated for each subject allowing for the identification of a variance component due to observed scores for the subjects. "Item" represents the item. The items are fixed (everyone responds to the same 10 items). Thus, we need not consider the variance associated with items directly (different situation, if different subjects were asked different questions). Item is included in our ANOVA model to partial out any systematic effects for the items. After accounting for systematic effects in both subjects (ISUB) and items (I) the remaining within error is seen as random (pure) error (E). This error component is given in the ERROR section of the table. VAR(E) = 0.175344 (MEAN SQUARE for ERROR). Then, 1.0123809 is the variance component for observed differences in subjects score (MEAN SQUARE for ISUB). Since VAR(X)=VAR(T)+VAR(E), we get VAR(T) = 1.01238 - 0.175344 = 0.837. Note with this approach one can account for other sources of variability as well.

Comment: If you add DF and SS for `ISUB` and `ITEM` you get DF and SS for Model. From there you can get MS Model. SS(Total) is the numerator of the sample variance of all 150 observations. Then SS(Total)/149 = MS(Total).

Comment: This for your answer. But how can I add DF and SS for     ISUB and     ITEM in R? Thanks!

Comment: For my taste, R leaves out information that I'm used to seeing in output of other software (and would occasionally find convenient). But I have to admit that the omitted information is usually easy to retrieve by other R procedures or to find (as here) by simple arithmetic.